# Extracting values from JMSE

Tags: javascript, json

[image]

I want extract text values from every sub objects the given JSON structure . For do that I have used following JMSEPath query `translations.en.*[0].[*].children.text` but I was not unable to extract the value . Can someone suggest me a correct query or other approches

Answer (score 0):

It may be better if you add to the question the expected output as well.
Making a big assumption that you want all text values "flatten up" into a single array you can try this: `translation.en.*[].children[].text`

Ref https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections